# Spring Cloud @FeignClient service name from properties file

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I want to set the service name in @FeignClient from a properties file, like this:

```
@FeignClient("${service.users}")
```

and have the name set in `application.yml` for example:

```
service.users: user-service
```

Where `user-service` is the name by which the service is registered in Eureka.

I have tried and it does not work. It complains for invalid name.

Can something like this be done?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If you did not get correct answer, please share your test project via git hub, i believe i  or someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143918/setting-class-level-annotation-values-from-application-yml

Answer (score 1):

It is an open [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/414). Pull requests are welcome :-)

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: Added in this [commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/94d4bdfcc38cb9cc505fe249a0f79f4431b03f8d).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done like this.

@FeignClient(name="fd-mobileapi-service",url="${fdmobile.ribbon.listOfServers}")

fdmobile.ribbon.listOfServers : value =>> this will be a property in application.properties.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem which requires the name property to be read from the configuration files. Anyway, the issue has been resolved in the following [commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/94d4bdfcc38cb9cc505fe249a0f79f4431b03f8d). I don't know when it will be released though.

Answer (score 1):

i tried to use similar configuration:

```
@FeignClient(name = "${spring.application.name:optional.application.name}")
```

application.yml,
bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-test-application
```

checking log after start

```
2016-05-24 16:11:00 [hystrix-my-test-application-1]                INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.prepareRefresh...
```

Also i had found in zookeeper active service

```
>ls /service/my-test-application 
[8668663c-cce1-4181-94de-4ccaacefa7e3]
```

checked in debug mode client bean - it was created

```
HardCodedTarget(type=EventBusClient, name=fnma-cp-test, url=http://my-test-application)
```

So this configuration should work.
My suggestions are:

1. check your client bean in runtime with hardcoded name (you need be sure that creates)
2. check visibility scope for your config file (your variable from config file can be out of scope)
3. check your application.yml - i do not sure, that spring comunity has reserved variable name 'service.users' by default (possible you need add special dependency). Or if you do not know dependency but needs use one,

please create next file structure:

```
 application.yml
 META-INF
 |-additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json
```

where additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json should have something like this

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "service.users",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "Description for service.users.",
      "defaultValue": "Some_Value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyway if any problems with **additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json** you can find explanations here: [enter link description here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html)