# Setting class level annotation values from application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was trying to externalise my configuration of a class level annotation using allication.yaml. But the spring is not loading it right. Any idea how to do this ?

Here is my Service classI am trying to set

```
   @Service
   @DefaultProperties(threadPoolProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = 
   "${cyclone.hystrix.lease.thread.coreSize}") })
    public class LeaseService {

   }
```

And application.yml

```
cyclone:
  hystrix:
    lease: 
      thread:
        coreSize: 10
```

Getting an error --

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad property value. property name 'coreSize'. Expected int value, actual = ${cyclone.hystrix.lease.thread.coreSize}
```

I can load the same property using @Value("${cyclone.hystrix.lease.thread.coreSize}"). But not working on the above mentioned case. 
Any help on how to properly configure this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make spring evaluate placeholders you need to register a  `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean using a static `@Bean` method when using `@Configuration` classes as follows:

```
@Bean 
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html):

> Specialization of PlaceholderConfigurerSupport that resolves ${...} placeholders within bean definition property values and @Value annotations against the current Spring Environment and its set of PropertySources.

Comment: Still with actual problem. The @value is working properly. But spring boot still not resolving the ${cyclone.hystrix.lease.thread.coreSize} given as value for above annotation. Any help ?