# Not able to pass config values in @HystrixProperty annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, microservices, hystrix

I am trying to pass properties values in @HystrixProperty annotation like below

```
  @HystrixProperty(name="circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value="${requestVolumeThreshold}")
```

Also Tried this

```
@HystrixProperty(name="circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value="#{${requestVolumeThreshold}}")
```

However its giving me exception "IllegalArgumentException";  bad property value
Where Am I going wrong ?

Comment: can you add how are you passing `requestVolumeThreshold` properties.

Comment: Can you share your properties file in Question ?

Comment: Please follow this link. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143918/setting-class-level-annotation-values-from-application-yml?rq=1